# Битрикс редакция "Бизнес"

Tags: 1с, дистрибутив, битрикс

Добрый день, друзья! У меня вопрос, где можно скачать «1С-Битрикс: Управление сайтом» редакции "Малый бизнес" или "Бизнес" АРХИВОМ, не в формате exe. Это нужно для того, чтобы не устанавливать на локальный компьютер эту систему. Дистрибутив нужен для загрузки на удаленный хостинг с последующей инсталляцией. Спасибо за ответы, если ответите...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел. Вот [ссылка](http://www.1c-bitrix.ru/download/cms.php#tab-php-link). 
Если кому интересно, то пригодится. Вопрос закрываю.

Answer (score 0):

Также достаточно удобно устанавливать систему 1с-битрикс скриптом bitrixsetup, скрипт доступен по данной ссылке [bitrixsetup](http://www.1c-bitrix.ru/download/scripts/bitrixsetup.php).

Достаточно кинуть данный файл в корень веб сервера и запустить в браузере.